# Android Studio Osmand project

Tags: java, android-studio, osmand

When I import an osmand project from GitHub (https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand) through my Android studio, I have two folders, one of them is called `osmand` and the other one is called `osmandCore`. I want to ask about the difference between these two folders and, when I want to run the application, which folder should I choose.

Also, after I run the `osmandCore` it asks me to download the osmand app from Play store to install the map and if I skip this step, no map shows in my app.

I want to know if there is any other way to install a map without returning to osmand in Play store, and if there is a way to import maps that I already downloaded from OpenStreetMap to my app.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should refer to the Osmand documentation regarding this questions.

Comment: Actually, I read almost of  Osmand documentation they do not mention anything about the difference between this two folder or if there is a possibility to import map inside my app.